# Some trouble when sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, collections

I've the same file with the same name in different folders.
I want to find the latest modified, so I use this script:

```
import os

from collections import OrderedDict


home = os.path.expanduser('~/')  # path of home, common for al users
result = []
time = {}
name = '.webpyconfig.ini'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d == '.Trash']
    if name in files:
        result.append(os.path.join(root, name))

for times in range(0, len(result)):
    time[times] = [result[times], os.stat(result[times]).st_mtime]
    time = OrderedDict(sorted(time.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
    maxtime = time[len(time) - 1][1]
    maxpath = time[len(time) - 1][0]


for k in range(0, len(time)):
    print time[k][1], time[k][0]

print ''
print maxtime, maxpath
```

And the result is:

```
1448636799.0 /Users/Leo/Desktop/Webpy/.webpyconfig.ini
1448637069.0 /Users/Leo/Desktop/Webpy2/.webpyconfig.ini
1448636937.0 /Users/Leo/Documents/Webpy/.webpyconfig.ini

1448636937.0 /Users/Leo/Documents/Webpy/.webpyconfig.ini
```

As you could see, the order is not correct because Webpy2 is the latest file created.
Some hint?

Comment: Why are you re-sorting the `time` ordered dictionary each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing a *list* as a value, and are sorting by that list:

```
time[times] = [result[times], os.stat(result[times]).st_mtime]
```

`x[1]` in your sort key is the whole list, containing `[path, time]` values. This means you sort first and foremost by the path, not the modification time.

You are overcomplicating this a bit; just add the time in the `os.walk()` loop, *just* the time:

```
results = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(home):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d == '.Trash']
    if name in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, name)
        results[path] = os.stat(path).m_time

sorted_by_mtime = OrderedDict(sorted(results.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1]))
for path, time in sorted_by_mtime.items():
    print time, path
```

Comment: Last question: how can I select only the last modify path? With the 'for path, time in sorted...' I print all the possibility, but I want only the newest one.

Comment: Don't use sorting then. You could use `max()` with the same key, or just test in the `os.walk()` loop if you found a newer path than the ones you have seen so far (store one path and its mtime and test new paths against that mtime).

Comment: I found this. I delete path and I write in the if loop 'code' result[root] = os.stat(root).st_mtime'code' and out of the for loop path_w = max(result.iterkeys(), key=lambda key: result[key])

Comment: You can drop the `.iterkeys()` part entirely.

Comment: I delete path and I write in the if loop result[root] = os.stat(root).st_mtime and out of the for loop 'path_w = max(result.iterkeys(), key=lambda key: result[key])'

Comment: Sure! But `max()` loops over the first object, and looping directly over a dictionary already gives you keys. So `max(result, key=result.get)` or is enough here. :-)